# When a model uses `:has_many` and nested routes, whats the resulting path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**Foreword** (because it is my first rails post)
I love rails but currently it drives me crazy!
I played around with rails 2.3 two years ago. Now I started with rails 3.1. All just for fun. Rails is the best and most professional I've ever seen in web development.
But... Since one line of code has so much power it is pretty hard to learn it!!!
The rail magic is hard to get :-)

**Problem**
I've got a nested models and routs. One page has_many articles.
I render pages/show.html.haml and in the page I list all articles. Each article shall have buttom underneath to 'new','edit' and 'destroy'.

```
render @articles
```

Here is my views/articles/_article.html.haml

```
%li.article_list{:id=>"a#{article.id}"}
    .article
        .article_head
            %h2
                =article.title:class => "icon"), '#'
        .clear
        .article_content
            = raw parse_content(article.content)
            -if admin?
                #article_menu
                    %ul
                        %li= link_to icon_new     + 'New...', new_page_article_path(@page)
                        %li=# link_to icon_edit    + 'Edit', edit_page_article_path(WHAT SHALL BE IN HERE???)
                        %li= link_to icon_destroy + 'Destroy', [article.page, article], :confirm => "#{article.title}\n\nAre you sure?", :method => :delete
```

**My problem is this line**

```
%li=# link_to icon_edit    + 'Edit', edit_page_article_path(WHAT SHALL BE IN HERE???)
```

I want to edit the article but I don't get the clue how to! I've tried and googled for hours!

In general I've been following this nice guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#associating-models

---

**Additional information**

models/article.rb

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :title, :content, :publish_at, :fan_only

      belongs_to :page

      validates :content, :presence => true
      validates :page_id, :presence => true

      default_scope :order => 'articles.created_at DESC'
    end
```

models/page.rb

```
   class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :short_name, :title, :content, :fan_only

      has_many :articles, :dependent => :destroy
    end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :pages do
    resources :articles
  end
```

part of the articles_controller.rb

```
  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
    @page = Page.find(params[:page_id])
    @article = @page.articles.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

`rake routes` should show you all the paths, and give you a hint as to what goes in there.

Based in the code you posted, the answer to what goes in there is that is should be a reference to a `PageArticle`, a `Page` or an `Article` - I'm not sure which it is, because I don't know what your models are.

With two models, `Page` and `Article`, and nested resources, then you should have a nested route in your `routes.rb` file that looks something like:

```
resources :pages do
  resources :articles
end
```

...which sets up a nested route to `/pages/:page_id/articles/:id/edit`

...and which looks like `edit_page_article_path(@page, @article)` in your app

**More detail on routing+nested resources:** http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You guessed my resources right and I have two models. I added further information to my post.
Unfortunately this doesn't work:
edit_page_article_path(@page, @article)

If I call http://localhost:3000/pages/1/articles/4/edit I get my edit mask but without content in...

Comment: I got it! I got it!

edit_page_article_path(@page, article)

Still no content but this is another storry.

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Awesome (looks like you already fixed it)! I updated my answer with a response to your updates.